# Properties of sigmoid functions

Tags: statistics

I'm considering a parametrized [sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function such as the following logistic:
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{a+bx}}{1+e^{a+bx}}$$
And I'm interested only in the interval $\displaystyle x >= 0$ and $\displaystyle x < x_{max}$ (with a given $x_{max}$).

Two tiny questions regarding its properties:

1) Is the **sum of sigmoid functions always a sigmoid function itself**?

2) Is the log function (i.e. $\displaystyle f(x) = log_{a}(bx^{c})$ or similar) **a particular case of a sigmoid function**? In other words, can I pick parameters for the logistic function above so that it behaves like a log function in the given interval?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can include a link to what exactly a sigmoid function is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that a sigmoid function is bounded, and its graph has exactly one inflection point (among other properties).

For (1), then, the answer is no.  If $f(x)=\frac{e^{3x}}{1+e^{3x}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{e^{2x-5}}{1+e^{2x-5}}$, then $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ can be seen to have two points of inflection, so h(x) is not sigmoid.

For (2), your function is unbounded on $0\le x \le x_{\mbox{max}}$, but sigmoid functions are bounded.  So these functions have decidedly different behavior.  Though, it does depend somewhat on what you mean by "like".

Comment: Thanks for the answer to (1). Regarding the answer to (2), i am only interested in the interval $[0, x_{max}]$. In this interval, is it possible to define a "parametrized" log function that corresponds to the sigmoid function defined above?

Comment: What do you mean by a parametrized log function?  Are you looking for a function which is identical to the sigmoid function, or one which is an approximation (i.e., what do you mean by correspond)?

Comment: I'm looking for something that is identical to the sigmoid function in the given interval.

Comment: Again: what do you mean by a parametrized log function?

Comment: Also, your function, equivalent to $d \ln x +e$ as Ross explained, is unbounded on $0 \le x \le x_{\mbox{max}}$.  Your sigmoid functions are not unbounded.  Thus sigmoid functions and your log functions cannot be identical.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to speak of "the sigmoid function".  The Wikipedia link shows that there are many to choose from.  For (2), note that $\displaystyle f(x) = \log_{a}(bx^{c})=c\log_{a}{x}+\log_{a}{b}=d\ln{x}+e$ by absorbing the constants into the change of base of log.  This is definitely not sigmoidal.